# Parsing JSON response from Google Maps

Tags: json, google-maps, go

I needed to create a proxy-server to connect to the google maps webservicees, and I found a tutorial that does about 95% of what I need.  The tutorial uses golang, I'm almost completely new to golang, and if I follow it exactly, it works fine.  But the moment I try to change something from the tutorial, I'm obviously messing something up, lol.

The issue that I need right now is that the tutorial only parses 2 variables from the google-maps response, the latitude and longitude.  For the rest of my app I ALSO need the place Id.

I'm receiving the response from google-maps, not a problem.  If I parse it as

```
type placeResults struct {
    Results []struct {
        Geometry struct {
            Location struct {
                Lat float64 `json:"lat"`
                Lng float64 `json:"lng"`
            } `json:"location"`
        } `json:"geometry"`
    } `json:"results"`
}
```

It works fine and gives me the latitude and longitude, no worries.

But if I instead try,

```
type placeResults struct {
    Results []struct {
        Geometry struct {
            Location struct {
                Lat float64 `json:"lat"`
                Lng float64 `json:"lng"`
            } `json:"location"`
        } `json:"geometry"`
        id struct {
            Id string `json:"id"`
        }
    } `json:"results"`
}
```

It tells me:

> json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field .Id of type struct { Id string "json:\"id\"" }

Now the id variable isn't part of the geometry, but is a generic part of the response, so I figured this would be the correct syntax.  Obviously I am wrong.  But what IS the correct syntax to include this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google place API response looks like,

```
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : -33.866651,
            "lng" : 151.195827
         },
         "viewport" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : -33.8653881697085,
               "lng" : 151.1969739802915
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : -33.86808613029149,
               "lng" : 151.1942760197085
            }
         }
      },
      "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
      "id" : "4f89212bf76dde31f092cfc14d7506555d85b5c7",
```

So you need to declare id field as string, not struct. You need to change placeResult structure.

```
type modifiedPlaceResult struct {
    Geometry struct {
        Location struct {
            Lat float64 `json:"lat"`
            Lng float64 `json:"lng"`
        } `json:"location"`
    } `json:"geometry"`

    Id string `json:"id"`
}
```

try use modifiedPlaceResult struct for Unmarshaling data, everything would be ok.
I attached the example from Go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Q4rM-jluoFe